# Cant play music due to file path using react-native-track-player REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio

im trying to play music in my device using debug mode, but it doesnt play even the file is right, heres the code:

initialize the player in componentDidMount:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.requestPermission();
    this.init_player();
}

init_player = async () => {
    await TrackPlayer.setupPlayer();
    await TrackPlayer.add({
        id: "1",
        url: "file:///storage/emulated/0/Download/Maluma-Hawai.mp3",
        title: "Dfdf",
        artist: "Dfdf",
    });
}
```

then in a button just call the method:

`TrackPlayer.play()`

but its not working, tried with `file://+path` and `file:///+path`

and im using android X

track player gitbuh: [music player](https://github.com/react-native-kit/react-native-track-player)

Comment: Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 2):

This one works for me:
I downloaded a track first to the DocumentDirectoryPath.
Then I can add to the url the following:

```
url: `file://${DocumentDirectoryPath}/GetLucky.m4a`
```

version:
"react-native-track-player": "^2.0.1",